# How to rotate multiple features from multiple layers in QGIS at once?

Tags: qgis, features, rotate, multiple

[image][image][image]I want to rotate multiple layers containing points, lines, polygons around a point.  According to my research, the tools in qgis can only rotate the features of the active layer together, is there a method or tool that can rotate multiple features from different layers at the same time? Also, the rotation point is determined by me and the features must rotate around that point

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data? You want to rotate each feature around its center?

Comment: I define the rotation point myself, the features rotate around my specified point.

Comment: What is the source of your data? For example, PostGIS data can be rotated easy with one query for each layer.

Comment: I have a lot of information in different layers and I want to rotate all selected features from different layers by specifying the rotation point with given angle.  I don't want to rotate the properties of each layer separately, because it would take too much time.

Comment: There is a plugin for operating on multiple layers at once.  Search on multiple layer in the plugin box.  I haven't tried these though.

Comment: I checked almost everything, I didn't find anything that would satisfy my needs.  Please tell me if there is a plugin so I can check it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Rotate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rotate) tool as a batch process for rotating more than one feature. You can specify the angle and the point of rotation. If you want the same rotation angle and point you can use the Autofill option.

[image]

Comment: The rotate tool didn't solve my need either, because all the features of each layer are rotated, while I have a number of selected features from each layer and I want only them to be rotated.  Does this tool work with the selected feature?

Comment: In Smallworld, it is possible to rotate selected features from different layers.  This functionality seems to be missing from QGis and should be added.  This feature will be very useful for users.

Comment: I have tried again for selected features without batch process. But it rotates all the features. I think it may not be possible with this tool. You can try exporting the selected features and rotating them. Later you can merge the rotated features with the original dataset.

Comment: I need to rotate the selected features from different layers, I can export the selected features and rotate them and later merge the rotated features with the original dataset.  But this is a temporary and time-consuming method, Smallworld has this feature and it is easy to rotate selected features from different layers.  Why Qgis, which is my favorite software, does not have this feature!?

Comment: I can understand, you are right. You can request for this feature in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues.